# Variable Naming Convention Thoughts for Swift 3

Tags: swift, naming-conventions, swift3, naming

**Concerning Variable Names:**
Suppose there is some code similar to the following:

```
class AgentModel
    var name: String?
    var office: String?
    var phone: String?
```

Would naming-convention dictate that these be named as

```
class AgentModel
    var nameString: String?
    var officeString: String?
    var phoneString: String?
```

I haven't been able to find if Apple definitively lays out guidelines for whether one practice is preferred or not, but it doesn't seem Swift-y to always follow the latter, except when necessary.

---

**Concerning Object Names**: Similarly, should the object even be named

```
AgentModel
```

or should it be named as follows?

```
Agent
```

At first glance, I would think that this would follow the same conventions. Am I correct, or would this be an exception to the rule?

---

Do people have thoughts and/or references for this?
Thanks!

Comment: As of Swift 3 you should definitely omit String from the var name

Comment: A good rule now is "Don't tell something that's already been told." We know that it's a String because it's typed as a String: no need to tell it again by adding it to the name. :)

Comment: From https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/: *"Name variables, parameters, and associated types according to their roles, rather than their type constraints."*

Comment: If you feel your question has been answered, please vote on the answers and accept one of them.

Comment: I was hoping for more discussion on "Agent" vs. "AgentModel", but the answer I just selected gets to the core of everything.

Comment: @EndersJeesh If you're going to specify the your `Agent` is a `Model`, shouldn't you also specify it's a struct (for example, but it could be a class)? Better call it `AgentModelStruct`! But wait, structs are types, and we should convey to users that our struct is a type, so `AgentModelStructType` would be even better! ... My point is, you can tack on plenty of words on, but ultimately they don't add much information, and don't pull their weight to be worth being included

Comment: I think of adding "Model" to the name as slightly different from Type information, because it is really information about the design model it is being used in -- just like Views often include View in their name and ViewControllers include ViewController in their name. However, I feel differently with "Model" because it is the closest object in the design pattern to being a "Type". So I could see an argument made for either and wanted to know other people's thoughts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) on [swift.org](https://swift.org) state (emphasis added):

> Omit needless words. Every word in a name should convey salient information at the use site.
>
> More words may be needed to clarify intent or disambiguate meaning, but those that are redundant with information the reader already possesses should be omitted. In particular, **omit words that merely repeat type information.**

And:

> Name variables, parameters, and associated types according to their **roles, rather than their type constraints.**

So

```
var nameString: String?
var officeString: String?
var phoneString: String?
```

is clearly *not* recommended.

```
var name: String?
var office: String?
var phone: String?
```

is good but may be improved further, such as using `phoneNumber`
instead of `phone`.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

If I needed to know the type and it wasn't obvious from context, I would just option click it and Xcode will give me its declaration, including its access specifier, type and mutability.

Comment: What about "Agent" vs. "AgentModel" for the object name itself -- especially when there isn't going to be another Agent object for it to conflict with?

Comment: I think I would go with `Agent` personally, but I don't really have a reason for it. I think the `Model` part is easily inferable, but either way should be fine.

Comment: @EndersJeesh Which is more readable: `Agent.phone = 123` or `AgentModel.phoneString = 123`? Whatever that is more readable is better!

Answer (score 0):

```
class AgentModel {
    var name: String?
    var office: String?
    var phone: String?
}

let agent = AgentModel()
agent.name = "EndersJeesh"
agent.office = "London Port"
agent.phone = "180059345345"
```

This will make life easy. Since the type is already specified in variable declaration "var name: **String**?" it won't makes sense to add the type in the variable name again.